# InnoSetup - How to detect if MySQL Workbench is installed?

Tags: mysql-workbench, inno-setup

I'm creating an installer for modeling software, and we encourage our users to install MySQL Workbench to access model output. However, because the MySQL installation process isn't exactly straight forward, many users end up only installing MySQL Server and fail to install MySQL Workbench. How can I detect during my installation process if MySQL Workbench is installed?

On my development machine, there is a registry entry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\Location. I could check to make sure that path exists, but this approach requires MySQL registry keys to be up-to-date (I've been burned relying on this approach trying to detect MySQL Server) and it is version specific.

- If it turns out that this is the best option, are there other registry paths that I would need to check?
- Am I safe checking MySQL Workbench 6.2 CE, MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE, MySQL Workbench 6.4 CE, etc, or are there other versions out there (e.g. non-"Community Edition")? This isn't apparent to me after spending some time on Workbench's website.

More information:
Since MySQL updates their package much more frequently than we update ours, we are hesitant to bundle a version of the MySQL MSI in our installation package and do a silent install, because it will likely be out of date. Instead, we detect if MySQL has been installed, and if not, we direct them to MySQL's download page and tell them to install MySQL Server and Workbench. This generally works for getting Server installed, but Workbench frequently fails (either because of the pre-reqs and MySQL Installer's non-intuitive prompts, or because they don't notice our recommendation). Therefore, I'm looking for a way to detect if Workbench is installed so I can offer a second prompt if needed.

Does the Workbench GUID stay the same over all the different versions? I'd hate to hard code one in and then have my installer be unable to detect newer/older/non-"Community Edition" versions.

Comment: Why don't you favor the MySQL installer for Windows? This installer comes with everything needed for MySQL (the server, WB, connectors, docs, examples). For installations: the typical approach is to look for product key. That's how MSI finds e.g. updates to make.

Comment: I added more information about what I'm trying to do to the question.